# is there a better function then check4winner() for my tictactoe board

Tags: javascript

```
function check4Winner(){    
    winningCombinations = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]];     
    for(var a = 0; a < winningCombinations.length; a++){
        if(squares[winningCombinations[a][0]]==currentPlayer&&
           squares[winningCombinations[a][1]]==currentPlayer&&
           squares[winningCombinations[a][2]]==currentPlayer){
             winner=true;
             alert(currentPlayer+ " WON!");              
        }           
    }//forloop  
}//end check4Winner().
```

Comment: Looks like a reasonable enough implementation to me. You could generalize this a bit, but for a 3x3 board it'd probably take more code to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I'd also `return` out of the loop to prevent duplicate winner dialogs:

```
function check4Winner(){    
    var winningCombinations = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]];

    for (var a = 0; a < winningCombinations.length; a++) {
        if (squares[winningCombinations[a][0]]==currentPlayer &&
            squares[winningCombinations[a][1]]==currentPlayer &&
            squares[winningCombinations[a][2]]==currentPlayer) {
             alert(currentPlayer+ " WON!");

             return true;           
        }           
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of that you could do is to collect statistical data about the frequency with which winning combinations occur.

Then you could order the combinations you check based on that frequency, placing the more frequently occurring winning combinations at the beginning of the list.

Comment: Isn't that overcomplicating it

Comment: All winning combinations occur with the exact same probability if you move randomly. If you're considering real games, my guess would be that the diagonals would occur least often, but the other combinations all occur equally likely due to the board's symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching google for other codes, like

- http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/tactoe.shtml
- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/247361-simple-tic-tac-toe-using-html5-css3-and-javascript/
- http://lppjunior.com/projects/jogo-da-velha/

and test which one is faster here: http://jsperf.com/

Answer (score 0):

Consider representing the 8 possible winning combinations as binary numbers (or convert to decimal, but binary is obvious), where 1 represents a selected square:

```
var winners = {'111000000':'', '000111000':'', '000000111':'', // hz
               '100100100':'', '010010010':'', '001001001':'', // vt
               '100010001':'', '001010100':''};                // diag
```

Then check after 3 turns if the user's selection converts to the appropriate binary number using `in`:

```
if (currentScore in winners) { 
  // ta da!
}
```

### Edit

Oh, to keep the score after a turn:

```
// Start with no score
var score = '000000000';

// Update score where num is selected square (0 to 8 inclusive)
score = score.substring(0, num) + '1' + score.substring(++num);
```

And you can use a regular expression for less code:

```
var winners  = /111000000|000111000|000000111|100100100|010010010|001001001|100010001|001010100/;
if (winners.test(score)) // ta da!

var winners = /^(448|56|7|292|146|73|273|84)$/; // using decimal numbers
if (winners.test(parseInt(score, 2))) // ta da!
```

How many ways can you skin a cat?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of another way to check if there is a winner. And here it is:

```
 var x, y, win;
            //RUN THRU ARRAYS ALL WIN POSS == A WIN
            for (x = 0; x < winningCombinations .length; x++) //if all three are equal to current string (either x or o)
            {
                for(y = 0;y < winningCombinations [x].length;y++)
                {
                    if(document.getElementById(win_Array[x][y]).innerText == check) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                    if(counter == 3)
                    {
                    alert(Check + 'Won!')
                    } 
                }
                counter = 0; //resets count before checking next possible wins
            }
```

Let me Explain what's happening here. The first for loop starts at index 0. The second for loop runs through all 3 index's of the first index. To illustrate: It runs through every single winning combo and checks if its equal to X or O. My variable `check` is defined by who's turn it was last. So if it was X's turn, then check = 'X'; Every time the if statement finds an X or O in the box, or in your case a winning combination is true, it adds +1 to a counter. When the counter reaches 3, that means that it found that there are 3 X's or O's and the rows are equal to each other. The counter = 0 part resets the counter before the value of x of the upper for loop changes. This prevents the program from finding 3 X's or O's anywhere and saying you won. As for alerting who won, that all depends on your variable and how you keep track of turns. I recommend passing both a counter variable and a check variable. The counter variable will count how many moves where made, and if it is = to 9, and there isn't any wins then it's a cat's game. The check variable like i said should depend on whose turn it is. I hope i explained this well...